# The C++ equivalent of C's format string

Tags: c++, c, scanf, cin, iomanip

I have a C program that reads from keyboard, like this:

```
scanf("%*[ \t\n]\"%[^A-Za-z]%[^\"]\"", ps1, ps2);
```

For a better understanding of what this instruction does, let's split the format string as follows:

`%*[ \t\n]\"` => read all spaces, tabs and newlines (`[ \t\n]`) but not store them in any variable (hence the '`*`'), and will keep reading until encounter a double quote (`\"`), however the double quote is not input.

Once `scanf()` has found the double quote, reads all caracters that are not letters into ps1. This is accomplished with...

`%[^A-Za-z]` => input anything not an uppercase letter 'A' through 'Z' and lowercase letter 'a' through 'z'.

`%[^\"]\"` => read all remaining characters up to, but not including a double quote into ps2 (`[^\"]`) and the string must end with a double quote (`\"`), however the double quote is not input.

Can someone show me how to do the same thing in C++

Thank you

Comment: It seems that what I said it's not clear for some people! 'cin exists in C++ to take the place of scanf of C, otherwise, we don't need 'cin', 'cout' and all the features C++ introduced.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, so you mean I can't read from console accordding some restrictions! Is that you said? Sorry but I don't belieave.

Comment: @0x5453 I don't want to refer scanf in C++. I wanna do the same without cstdio

Comment: `std::cin` is used more for straight forward reading of words.  For more advanced stuff, us [std::regex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex)

Comment: @appleapple, I read that on a book

Comment: Yeah, also a comment from me because it is mostly a link to std::regex.  If you know regular expressions, it should be reasonable to translate, but you will need more code.

Comment: @stefaanv, ok, can you please write the regex for me?

Answer (score 3):

C++ supports the `scanf` function. There is no simple alternative, especially if you want to replicate the exact semantics of `scanf()` with all the quirks.

Note however that your code has several issues:

- You do not pass the maximum number of characters to read into `ps1` and `ps2`. Any sufficiently input sequence will cause a buffer overflow with dire consequences.
- You could simplify the first format `%*[ \t\n]` with just a space in the format string.  This would also allow for the case where no whitespace characters are present. As currently written, `scanf()` would fail and return `0` if no whitspace characters are present before the `"`.
- Similarly, if no non letters or if no other characters follow before the second `"`, `scanf` would return a short count of `0` or `1` and leave one or both destination array in an indeterminate state.

For all these reasons, it would be much safer and predictable in C to first read a line of input with `fgets()` and use `sscanf()` or parse the line by hand.

In C++, you definitely want to use the `std::regex` package defined in `<regex.h>`.