# Can I redirect "cin" to function with regex?

Tags: c++, regex, cin

I'm having my head around for a couple of days with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40743948/the-c-equivalent-of-cs-format-string) question, and I still can't solve my problem.

If I need to read two strings from keyboard I can do this:

```
cin >> str1 >> str2;
```

However I want to filter the input.

What I'm trying to do, is something like this:

```
cin >> filter1 >> str1 >> filter2 >> str2;
```

or alternatively

```
cin >> filter1 >> filter2 >> str1 >> str2;
```

Where *filter1* and *filter2* are functions with regexes for filter the input.

My biggest trouble is I can't see how to insert the functions, between the input and the strings. .

Any help appreciated

Comment: Would you tolerate `>> filter(str1)`? I think that would be easier to implement.

Comment: Yes, but in that case would be cin >> filter1(str1) >> filter2(str2)? Like that?

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Sorry my last comment was hogwash. I thought you could get away with `filter(str1) >> filter(str2)`

Comment: How can I redirect from 'cin' to a function?

Comment: You can easily create you own *manipulators* similar to the standard manipulators. However the problem here, I think, is the actual *filtering*. I don't think there is a way to skip the next extraction. So a solution where you create a manipulator that takes the variable as an argument (as suggested by @Bathsheba) would be the best solution.

Comment: I can do cin >> str but I can't cin >> filter(str)

Comment: `filter` would actually be a class which has a constructor to a string type. It then has an overloaded >> to an istream.

Comment: Overload to istream is out of my knowledge :-(

Comment: Please [find a good book to read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). That will teach you how to overload operators like `>>`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I know how to do operator overloading. The problem is the iostream.

Comment: Overloading the input and output (actually the bitwise shift operators) for streams is no different than overloading other functions and operators. Again, please pick up a book as it will tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, ok, I'll do that. Thank you.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I follow your advice and already know how to overload `>>` and `<<` with `istream` and `ostream`. My problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Your filter function should return object of class that implements filtering using regex. Then you would overload operator>> to accept that object, which would read data and invoke it. Peek into istream header to get idea how to do that. Object must be destroyed or it may be a singleton of some kind